# Can I import Lua files directly from within Python code?

Tags: python, lua, site-packages, lupa

I'm new to Python and using Pycharm.
I have an application in Python and I wan't to be able to import Lua files and use them(the functions, variables and etc.) from within Python.
Searching in google I found this website "https://pypi.org/project/lua-imports/" and it seems possible.
According to this page, "lua_importer" moudle may be registered within Python code.
Can you please explain me how to register it properly?
I barely found information about this issue and no matter what I do, when I'm trying to import a Lua file Python doesn't recognize it.
Thank you :)

I tried to import lua files and be able to run lua functions from within Python.

Comment: Why do you think Python can recognize Lua files?

Comment: Short answer: No. Lua is not Python and Python is not Lua. Not so short answer: You can use bindings to a Lua interpreter - or, theoretically, a Lua interpreter written in Python - to execute Lua from Python.

Comment: First you should add the module `lua_imports` to your Python.

Comment: `lua_imports` seems to be buggy.  It successfully found `foo.lua` module, but failed to get its content: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'say_hello'`

Comment: Try to use [Lupa](https://github.com/scoder/lupa) directly, without `lua_imports`